# Can I install Ubuntu touch in a Yarvik tablet?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I would like to install ubuntu touch on my tablet "yarvik", but I don't speak English well and I don't understand all text from your site. Can you help me with installation? Can I install on my tablet?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install#Supported_devices_and_codenames, only these devices are officially supported:

- Galaxy Nexus
- Nexus 4
- Nexus 7
- Nexus 10

There are also community-contributed models [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices#Working.2C_but_not_available_from_cdimage.ubuntu.com).

If your device is not on these two lists, then it's currently not possible.